# I have problem in function closure in python

Tags: python, oop

I have a function called path exists which as indicated in the code below check whether a certain given path exists in the system. I wanted to create a function closure (data exists function) which generalizes the path exists function to whatever number of paths the user need to check their availability.

What happens is when I pass a list of directories, what is actually passed to the inner function inside data_exists function is [path_exists function object, [ directories ] ]. So to access the directories I needed to index the outer list to the inner list.

If could anybody please help me to understand why is this happening ? and why a function object is passed through the _inner function.

What happens is

```
class VirufyAugmenter:
    def __init__(self, audiodir: str, dfdir: str):
        assert self.path_exists([audiodir, dfdir]), "Data directory doesn't exist"

        self.audiodir = audiodir
        self.dfdir = dfdir

        self.__classes = ("positive", "negative")
        self.__columns = ("patient_id", "pcr_test_result_inferred", "cough_path")

    def data_exists(path_exists) -> bool:
        """ Takes several directories [audiodir, dataframe dir] and returns single boolean"""

        @functools.wraps(path_exists)
        def _inner(*dirs):
            return functools.reduce(lambda a, b: path_exists(dirs[0], a) & path_exists(dirs[0], b), dirs[1])

        return _inner

    @data_exists
    def path_exists(self, dir: str) -> bool:
        return Path(dir).exists()
```

Comment: decorators are hard and make me sad :(

Comment: when you say "paths" are you talking about a file server path?

Answer (score 0):

That's simply a needlessly hard, not to mention inefficient way to do things.

Assuming there could be more than two directories in the future, you can use `all()`:

```
class VirufyAugmenter:
    def __init__(self, audiodir: str, dfdir: str):
        assert all(Path(d).exists() for d in [audiodir, dfdir]), "Data directory doesn't exist"

        self.audiodir = audiodir
        self.dfdir = dfdir

        self.__classes = ("positive", "negative")
        self.__columns = ("patient_id", "pcr_test_result_inferred", "cough_path")
```

But for now, I'd just do

```
class VirufyAugmenter:
    def __init__(self, audiodir: str, dfdir: str):
        assert Path(audiodir).exists() and Path(dfdir).exists(), "Data directory doesn't exist"

        self.audiodir = audiodir
        self.dfdir = dfdir

        self.__classes = ("positive", "negative")
        self.__columns = ("patient_id", "pcr_test_result_inferred", "cough_path")
```

Comment: Thank you and I agree with you that my way is needlessly hard but do you know why such thing happen ? that python object is being passed along with function argument

Comment: Probably because the original code is buggy and does that. (The use of `reduce` seems wrong too, since it keeps evaluating the existence of a truth value as a path...)

Comment: I am using reduce because I want to have a single true or false value representative for all directories existence: something similar to : True & True & False = False

Comment: Yes - that's what `all()` does in my fixed version.

Answer (score 0):

I use an closure to determine if a list of directories all exist. If any of the directories do not exist then an assertion error is thrown by the closure function in the class.

```
import os 
class VirufyAugmenter:
    def __init__(self, paths):
         assert self.path_exists(paths)
         self.paths=paths
    
    def path_exists(self,paths):
         result=False
         for path in paths:
              result=os.path.isdir(path)
              if result==False:
                  break
         return result

paths=["c:\\"]
obj=VirufyAugmenter(paths)
print(obj)
```

Output:
The closure executes without an assertion

```
paths=["c:\\","d:\\"]
obj=VirufyAugmenter(paths)
print(obj)
```

Output:
The closure path_exists executes with an assertion error